# How to choose between Node.js and web API?

Tags: node.js, asp.net-web-api

I am re-designing an ASPX web project. Should I choose Node.js or web API? Which factors should I consider?

Comment: Asking which to choose (node vs webapi) is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's asking for a tool/framework recommendation, and it's opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The out-of-the-box performance of the Node.js is faster if your looking for speed. Here a bench mark test of both http://mikaelkoskinen.net/asp-net-web-api-vs-node-js-benchmark-take-2/ to see the difference in performance. Other than that it's more of a personal chose.

Comment: those benchmarks are 3 years old. FYI. nodejs v.0.6 and WebApi (1)

Comment: Right - it's a personal choice. This question is only going to generate opinions, which is why it should be closed. There's no right answer to this question.